# Importing Products to New Magento Installation - Help

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, database, upgrade, backup

I have a second Magento store which for some reason will not upgrade to the latest version of Magento.

It's currently version 1.8.1 but I want to upgrade to 1.9.2.  We have tried numerous times but it keeps throwing errors at us and ultimately we have to restore the store from a backup each time.  It's very frustrating.

Is it possible to start a fresh by downloading Magento 1.9.2 and importing the databases and images from the backup file?

This isn't something I've done before so I don't know what the correct/most efficient procedure is to do it.

If anyone can help at all it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Set up all your files again in a fresh installation`.
2. `Copy your current database for testing purposes`
3. `Set you local.xml in the new location for the copied database`
4. `See what happens?`

**Concrete troubleshoot:**

Try to update magento not by the manager, but manually (overwrite files). This should throw less errors.

On the other hand, you could consult these pages with the Errors displayed. It might be something very easy like filerights.